# Can you get Barla Von's mission after talking to Liara's father?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Is it still possible to talk to Liara to get the Barla Von mission after you've made her talk with her father? Because she seems to just hang at the bar afterwards...

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant. This happened to me as well, and you can still get the mission by talking to Barla Von.

Liara doesnt start the mission itself, and you have to complete the mission before starting "Priority: Tuchanka"